# How can I interface with RPi-Camera to FPGA?

Tags: raspberry-pi, camera

I want to interface with RPi-Camera to my FPGA bord.

As you can see,  http://www.wvshare.com/product/RPi-Camera-B.htm

This camera has a 15pin-ffc cable. But I can't get a ffc cable's interface information of RPi-Camera.

Does anyone knows each pin's infomations of 15pins-ffc?
Also does anyone knows the reference site or resference things to interface RPi-Camera with FPGA?

Comment: There seems to be a datasheet on the product page.  Perhaps, the pin information is there.

Comment: @Nick Alexeev : I tried to find it with so much time but I can't

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RPi uses MIPI CSI-2 interface.

Lattice Semi has a good reference design document for the MIPI CSI2-to-CMOS Parallel Sensor Bridge.

Comment: But I can't use MIPI. I have to use parallel instead of using MIPI. As I seen specification, There are might some options in there.

Comment: The Lattice document describes how to convert the CSI-2 interface signals to a parallel bus (6 - 24 bit wide) using their FPGAs.

Comment: You can also use this ASIC chip from Toshiba: http://www.toshiba.com/taec/components/ProdBrief/11J02_TC358746_ProdBrief.pdf

Comment: If yoh don't mind, would you give me a link of the Lattice you have concerned?

Comment: Google "MIPI CSI2-to-CMOS Parallel Sensor Bridge"